# Display product attributes values for specific categories in WooCommerce product loops

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, taxonomy-terms

I'm building a shop in WP + WooCommerce. I have different types of product categories like discs and bags. For discs products I have some specific attributes like Speed, Glide, Turn and Fade that don't have any other product categories. I want to display these product attribute values only on shop pages under the product picture.

I have found one code for that and I added myself a separation symbol "|", but this separation symbol is now displayed under all the products that are variable.

Is it possible to change the code not to variables but only for specific product categories and sub-categories?

[image]

Code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'display_size_attribute', 5 );

function display_size_attribute() {
    global $product;
    
    if ( $product->is_type('variable') ) {
        
        $taxonomy = 'pa_speed';
        echo '<span class="attribute-speed">' . $product->get_attribute($taxonomy) . '</span>' ;
        echo ' | ';
        $taxonomy = 'pa_Glide';
        echo '<span class="attribute-Glide">' . $product->get_attribute($taxonomy) . '</span>';
        echo ' | ';
        $taxonomy = 'pa_Turn';
        echo '<span class="attribute-Turn">' . $product->get_attribute($taxonomy) . '</span>';
        echo ' | ';
        $taxonomy = 'pa_Fade';
        echo '<span class="attribute-Fade">' . $product->get_attribute($taxonomy) . '</span>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a comment below my answer in the comment zone, if you want to say something and if you want me to get notified.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following revisited code instead to get separated attribute values only if they exist on your variable products:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'display_some_attributes', 5 );
function display_some_attributes() {
    global $product;

    if ( $product->is_type('variable') ) {
        $attributes = array('speed', 'Glide', 'Turn', 'Fade'); // here you defined attribute slugs
        $output     = array(); // Initializing

        // Loop through product attributes
        foreach ( $attributes as $attribute ) {
            $taxonomy = 'pa_' . $attribute;
            $values   = $product->get_attribute($taxonomy);

            // If not empty add it to the array
            if ( ! empty($values) ) {
                $output[] = '<span class="attribute-' . $attribute . '">' . $values . '</span>';
            }
        }
        // Convert array to a separated string by pipes
        echo implode(' | ', $output);
    }
}
```

To target specific product categories only, replace in the code the block:

```
    global $product;

    if ( $product->is_type('variable') ) {
```

with *(where you will define your product categories terms)*:

```
    global $product;

    $categories = array( 'cats', dogs' ); // Here your category terms ids, slugs or names

    if ( $product->is_type('variable') && has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: My code displays any non empty attribute values, including "0", as I use `empty()` so empty is `null` or `''` (an empty string)…

Comment: Thank you for your support. Everything worked well, but somehow it doesn't show the value if it is 0 (zero). For example, I have the attribute "Turn" set as 0 and it doesn't display.

Screenshots - https://imgur.com/a/C6UtUvP