# Bind set of product attributes to certain WooCommerce category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I import affiliate products into certain WooCommerce category. Import happens automaticall with cronjob. Imported products have some product attributes, which are imported too. But I have a set of additional product attributes, common for all products in this category (products are currently in the category and those will be imported in the future).

How can I bind a set of attributes to a category, so all products are automatically get them?

Comment: Check This Link [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66651549/display-product-attributes-values-for-specific-categories-in-woocommerce-product) This Can Help You To Solve Your Problem

Answer (score 1):

**Here are two ways to do it:**

```
add_action('woocommerce_new_product', 'assign_color_attributes', 10, 1);
function assign_color_attributes($product_id) {
    // Get the product object
    $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
    
    // Check if the product is in the specific category
    if (has_term('your-category-slug', 'product_cat', $product_id)) {
        
        // Assign color attributes
        $attributes = $product->get_attributes();
        $color_attribute = wc_get_attribute('pa_color');
        
        // Check if the color attribute exists
        if ($color_attribute && !isset($attributes['pa_color'])) {
            $attributes['pa_color'] = array(
                'name'         => 'Color',
                'value'        => 'Red,Blue',
                'is_visible'   => 1,
                'is_variation' => 1,
                'is_taxonomy'  => 1,
            );
            
            // Set the updated attributes
            $product->set_attributes($attributes);
            $product->save();
        }
    }
}
```

The first code snippet modifies the product's attribute object directly and sets the attribute values using the set_attributes() method provided by WooCommerce. This approach allows for more control over the attribute settings, such as visibility, variation, and taxonomy.

```
// Hook into the 'woocommerce_new_product' action
add_action('woocommerce_new_product', 'assign_color_attribute');

function assign_color_attribute($product_id) {
    // Get the product object
    $product = wc_get_product($product_id);

    // Check if the product is in a specific category
    $categories = $product->get_category_ids();

    if (in_array('your-category-slug', $categories)) {
        // Create a new term for the color attribute
        $color_attribute = 'red,blue';

        // Set the color attribute for the product
        wp_set_object_terms($product_id, $color_attribute, 'pa_color', true);
    }
}
```

The second code snippet uses the WordPress function wp_set_object_terms() to set the color attribute for the product. This function is more concise and simpler to use but provides less fine-grained control over the attribute settings.

In terms of simplicity and ease of use, the second code snippet is more straightforward. However, if you require more advanced attribute settings or plan to modify the attribute behavior in the future, the first code snippet is recommended as it provides greater flexibility.

Ultimately, the choice between the two snippets depends on your specific requirements and preferences for managing product attributes in WooCommerce.